# Get all power options available

Tags: c#, windows-8, sleep, shutdown

I have Windows 8 and the Power options are too hard to get to so i want to make a little app to replicate Power tab.

What i can't do is find a way to make windows Sleep. In windows 8 when the PC is Sleeping it is completely stopped and if you press a key it goes to Lock Screen instantaneously without the boot screen.

How can I accomplish that?

**UPDATE:** Or if it is possible to get a list of all power options available. ie: if hibernation is allowed...

I am using `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` to sleep PC now but it wakes very slow.

Comment: are you sure you are putting the pc to sleep and not hibernating it?

Comment: What's wrong with the [`SetSuspendState` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201.aspx)? [Most people use rundll32.exe incorrectly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://codehill.com/2009/01/lock-sleep-or-hibernate-windows-using-c/) should help you.

I think you can lock the pc and then put it to sleep.

To lock the screen:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

For entering sleep mode:

```
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Win-RT, then you should use the "suspension manager":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx
- http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/process-lifetime-management